# Divide value equally to each day of the month

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc053b896fce9e4b7f938323044f9df5)**

```
CREATE TABLE PaL (
     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    marketing_costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO PaL
(event_date, marketing_costs)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', '500'),
('2020-01-08', '900'),
('2020-01-20', '700'),
('2020-02-15', '600'),
('2020-02-23', '500'),
('2020-03-04', '300'),
('2020-03-19', '800'),
('2020-03-31', '100');


CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE
);

INSERT INTO dates
(date)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01'),
('2020-01-02'),
('2020-01-03'),
('2020-01-04'),
('2020-01-05'),
('2020-01-06'),
('2020-01-07'),
('2020-12-31');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date      |    marketing_costs            | 
----------------|-------------------------------|----
2020-01-01      |     67.74   (=2100/31)        | 
2020-01-02      |     67.74   (=2100/31)        |
2020-01-03      |     67.74   (=2100/31)        |
2020-01-04      |     67.74   (=2100/31)        | 
:               |     :                         |
:               |     :                         |
:               |     :                         |
2020-03-29      |     35.48   (=1100/31)        |
2020-03-30      |     35.48   (=1100/31)        |
2020-03-31      |     35.48   (=1100/31)        |
```

---

In the above table I have `marketing_costs` on different `event_dates`. 
In the expected result I want to divide the `marketing_costs` **equaly to each day of the month**.

Since in `redshift` I am not able to create monthly dates within a query I also have a supporting table called `dates` that includes every date of the year.

So far I am able to get the total `marketing_costs` per month but I do not have any clue how I have to modify the query to get them assigned to each day equally.

```
SELECT
DATE_TRUNC('month', pl.event_date)::date AS month,
SUM(pl.marketing_costs)
FROM PaL pl
GROUP BY 1;
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If you have full months in the data, then you can just use window functions:

```
    select 
   d.date, 
   p.marketing_costs,
           p.marketing_costs / count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('month', d.date) as allocated_costs
    from dates d left join
         pal p 
         on d.date = p,event_date;
```

---

`Modified answer by OP:` Using the above solution I could make it work with this query:

```
SELECT 
d.date AS date_list,
t1.marketing_costs,
(SUM(t1.marketing_costs) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month', d.date))) / DATE_PART('day', DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, +1, DATE_TRUNC('month', d.date)))::date) AS marketing_costs_per_day
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN

      (SELECT 
      pl.event_date AS event_date,
      SUM(pl.marketing_costs) AS marketing_costs
      FROM PaL pl
      GROUP BY 1) t1 ON t1.event_date = d.date

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1;
```